# Why can I change the Opacity but not the Background?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, coloranimation

I'm trying to do a `ColorAnimation` on my ComboBox that changes the background color of it when I hover over it with the mouse. But for some reason it won't change the background. If I try to to the same thing, but instead, I target the `Opacity` it works just fine, changing the Opacity, not the background.

I decided to work from a clean copy of the ControlTemplate and change it from there, I've made a couple of changes like changing the static background for instance, and I've commented a few things out that I didn't seem was needed.
So far I've tried to add some Style Triggers in the form of a EventTrigger which uses a `RoutedEvent` and I've been using `Border.MouseEnter` for the event itself, which seems to work just fine, it reacts when the mouse enters the ComboBox. And when it leaves.

This is the part where I'm trying to actually change the background when the mouse hovers over

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="Orange" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                    AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)"
                                    From=".5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="False" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
```

And I can't really create a minimalistic example, because I feel like it's needed to provide the entire style so nothing gets left out.

```
<Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#2ecc71" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#27ae60" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>

        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border" Color="#FFABADB3"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEBF4FC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF7EB4EA"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF000000"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAECFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDAEBFC" Offset="0.0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFC4E0FC" Offset="1.0"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border" Color="#FF569DE5"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFD9D9D9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border" Color="#FFBFBFBF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border" Color="Transparent"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ComboBox.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF606060"/>
        <Style x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">

            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="Orange" 
                                    Duration="0:0:0.2" 
                                    AutoReverse="False" FillBehavior="Stop" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>

                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Opacity)"
                                    From=".5" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.2" AutoReverse="False" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>

            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
            <Setter Property="ClickMode" Value="Press"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                        <Border x:Name="templateRoot" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Border x:Name="splitBorder" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}">
                                <Path x:Name="arrow" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 2.667,2.66665 L 5.3334,0 L 5.3334,-1.78168 L 2.6667,0.88501 L0,-1.78168 L0,0 Z" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <!--<MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>

                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="Orange" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>-->



                                <!--<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot">
                                    --><!--<Setter.Value>
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                 This works 
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.Color"
                                            To="#27ae60" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </Setter.Value>-->
                                    <!--<Setter.Value>
                                        --><!--<BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard>
                                                <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                                            To="Orange" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>-->
                                        <!--<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                            <GradientStop Color="#2ED571" Offset="0.0"/>
                                            <GradientStop Color="#2ED576" Offset="1.0"/>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush>--><!--
                                    </Setter.Value>--><!--
                                </Setter>-->
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Transparent"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.MouseOver.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Pressed.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="arrow" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEditable, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ComboBox}}}" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="splitBorder" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Disabled.Editable.Button.Border}"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" Width="0"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="shadow" Color="Transparent" MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}" MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=templateRoot}">
                        <Border x:Name="dropDownBorder" CornerRadius="0,0,5,5"  BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                                <Grid x:Name="grid" RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                        <Border x:Name="opaqueRect" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=dropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=dropDownBorder}"/>
                                    </Canvas>
                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Border>
                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                </Popup>
                <ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"/>
                <ContentPresenter TextBlock.Foreground="White" x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemStringFormat}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsHitTestVisible="false" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </Grid>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="shadow" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="shadow" Value="#71000000"/>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Height" TargetName="dropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                </Trigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true"/>
                        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false"/>
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                </MultiTrigger>
                <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="DropDownScrollViewer" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="opaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=DropDownScrollViewer}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TextBox.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>


        <Style x:Key="KIWI.ComboboxTheme" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#252525"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Fonts/#Roboto"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>

            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
            <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

I expect the background color of the ComboBox to fade into a different color that I set in the ColorAnimation, it fades since there is a slight Duration set, but at the moment it doesn't change color what so ever, but it does change the opacity when leaving the ComboBox.

Comment: Combobox inherently will not allow you to manipulate the background, in the style you have posted identify the right XAML node and try to see if you can manually change the background. Once you identify the right area to manipulate I think you would get this whole thing working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Trigger directly instead of an EventTrigger, it's work fine for me :

```
<Style.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
            Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background"
              Value="Orange" />
   </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

If you want to use animations, the VisualStates in the template seem more appropriate :

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                            <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5">
                                <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                                    <CircleEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
                                </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                            </VisualTransition>
                        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background)"
                                                               Storyboard.TargetName="Rectangle">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed" />
                        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```